# How to use reflect to instant a GENERIC class in JAVA?

Tags: java, reflection

I wanna instant a generic class, like `SomeContainer<SomeClass>`. I just have the className, so, use java reflect, like `Class.forNameClass.forName(param).newInstance();` but it doesn't support generic, how can I do ?

Comment: Well, you cant. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html for the reasoning behind it. Besides: you really want to do some prior research on the language features you are using.

Comment: Well,  actually, I know it, but what I want to serialize the `generic object` to json, and deserialize the json to origin object, but in deserialize end, it just have the class name of hte generic class, how to do?

Answer (score 1):

Generics are only syntax sugar at compile time, that allows Java to check the usage of types better and to avoid casts. At runtime, generics do not really exist. So e.g. a `List<String>` or a `List<Integer>` are all just instances of `List` at runtime.

To answer your question:

```
final Object o = Class.forName("java.util.List").newInstance();
final List<String> list = (List<String>) o;
```

Comment: Well, actually, I know it, but what I want to serialize the generic object to json, and deserialize the json to origin object, but in deserialize end, it just have the class name of hte generic class, how to do?